# PDOException could not find driver - Homestead Laravel

Tags: nginx

[image: Homestead system]

[image: PDO extension]

Upon running: `php artisan migrate` I recieve:

```
[PDOException]         
could not find driver
```

With me being unable to run database migrations through `artisan`.

As far as I can see my Nginx instance has `PDO` enabled and supporting `mysql` which is what I'm using on my local machine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed the PDO extension on *my* local machine, not the vagrant box

`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Following that we need to adjust our `.env` file for Laravel, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756194/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes
wdog

for a description

Comment: If this is solved, please mark it as solved by clicking the tick mark at the left so that it turns solid green. Welcome to [sf]!